# Problem connecting between containers in Pod

Tags: docker, podman

I have a pod with 3 containers in it: client, server, mongodb (MERN)
The pod has a mapped id to the host and the client listens to it -> 8184:3000

The website comes up and is reachable. Server logs says that it has been conented to the mogodb and is listening at port 3001 as I have assigned.

It seems that the client can not connect to the server side and therefor can not check the credentials for login which leads to get wrong pass or user all the time.
The whol program works localy on my windows.

Am I missing some part in docker or crating the pod. As far as I undrstood the containers in a pod should communicate as if they were running in a local network.

This is the gitlab-yml:

```
stages:
- build

 variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTERY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTERY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  TAG_NAME_Client: gitlab.comp.com/sdx-licence-manager:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-client
  TAG_NAME_Server: gitlab.comp.com/semdatex/sdx-licence-manager:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-server

  cache:
      paths:
         - client/node_modules/
         - server/node_modules/

  build_pod:
      tags:
         - sdxuser-pod-shell
        stage: build
        script:
- podman pod rm -f -a
- podman pod create --name lm-pod-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -p 8184:3000

build_db:
  image: mongo:4.4
  tags:
    - sdxuser-pod-shell
  stage: build
  script:
    - podman run -dt --pod lm-pod-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -v ~/lmdb_volume:/data/db:z --name mongo -d mongo
build_server:
  image: node:16.6.1
  stage: build
  tags:
    - sdxuser-pod-shell
  script:
    - cd server
    - podman build -t $TAG_NAME_Server .
    - podman run -dt --pod lm-pod-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA $TAG_NAME_Server
build_client:
  image: node:16.6.1
  stage: build
  tags:
    - sdxuser-pod-shell
  script:
    - cd client
    - podman build -t $TAG_NAME_Client .
    - podman run -d --pod lm-pod-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA $TAG_NAME_Client
```

Docker File Server:

```
FROM docker.io/library/node:16.6.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Docker File Client:

```
FROM docker.io/library/node:16.6.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g npm@7.21.0
COPY  . ./


EXPOSE 3000
# start app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

snippet from index.js at clientside trying to reach the server side checking log in credentials:

```
function Login(props) {
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

async function loginUser(credentials) {
            return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3001/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
            })
                .then((data) => data.json());
        }
 }
```

pod:
[image]

Comment: (You say "pod" and reference [tag:kubernetes], but the question doesn't otherwise seem like a Kubernetes question; do you have Deployment and Service objects in your setup, for example?  [tag:podman] is a separate tool that's not really related.)

Comment: sorry, you are right. I should have clicked kubernates as it was offerd by the webpage. I am using gitlab and the pipeline runs successfully. The pod and the containers are created but it seems that the client can not reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it has nothing to do with podman. Sorry about that. I added a proxy to my package.json and it redirected the requests correctly:
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"